# Put button outside vue-element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using the vuestrap-repo and am now trying to implement the 'aside' where a div slides in.

I get it all working when I put the button with the directive and the aside-element in one containing element like below:

```
<div id="leftMenu">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" v-on="click:showLeft=true">OPEN MENU</button>

    <aside show="@{{@showLeft}}" placement="left" header="Title" width="350">
        CONTENT HERE
    </aside>
</div>

<script>
var aside = VueStrap.aside;
new Vue({
    el: '#leftMenu',
    components: {
        'aside': aside
    },
    data: {
        showLeft: false
    }
});
</script>
```

The problem now is that I need to put the button in my navbar while the aside needs to be in the body (not nested) because of z-index issues of the overlay.

Is it possible to change the show-value in one div while the button is in a div with an other id ?

I tried with classes but without success.

```
el: '.leftMenu'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish what you want using child components.  Since it expects it to be a child of the DOM element.

Instead I'd suggest you create two Vue instances and have them share a common global data var that gets modified when the user clicks the menu button.

```
<div id="nav">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" v-on="click:showLeft">OPEN MENU</button>
</div>
<div id="leftMenu">
    <aside show="@{{@showLeft}}" placement="left" header="Title" width="350">
        CONTENT HERE
    </aside>
</div>

<script>
var showLeftGlobal = false;

new Vue({
    el: '#leftMenu',
    data: {
        showLeft: showLeftGlobal
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#nav',
    data: {
        showLeft: showLeftGlobal
    },
    methods: {
        showLeft: function() {
            // Toggle show
            showLeftGlobal = showLeftGlobal ? false : true;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```